# How to connect my website and database on the server

Tags: sql

I have a question about how to connect the database to my website. I have a server on Web Hosting Canada, and I just create a database through cPanel of this server but I don't know how to connect it to my website on the server. Sorry for maybe asking a silly question, I am really new to web dev (just learned for two weeks, know some HTML, css, javascript and node.js). And what else languages I need to learn? I watched a lot of tutorials, but they are all using node.js to build a local server. I think it is different from my situation. Please help, Thanks!

Comment: You need a connector between your database and your node.js app. You would typically use an npm package for this. For example, for MySQL there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql, as well as others. Research the one applicable to your database and read its documentation before using it in your app.

Comment: I know that node.js can build a server and then connect to the database, but in my case, I already have a server on Web Hosting Canada. How can I do so?